# SSRS Report Based On Days With Different Months

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I apologize if this has already been asked or something extremely similar to it. I've looked around a bit and couldn't find any results that worked for me.

I'm looking to format a SSRS report with a line graph. The bottom will contain the number of days remaining in the month (26 -> 0 (Sundays are SKIPPED)) Please see the image for clarity.

Then I want each month to be on the line graph in a different color, all starting in nearly the same place (26/25/24 days remaining) and all lines ending in the same place (0).

The image (excel spreadsheet) seems to sum all of this up perfectly.

Left side is a count (irrelevant) and the bottom is the days remaining with each line containing a month (January, February, March)

Again, I apologize if this has been posted before.

Output sample

`LoanNumberCount TestBucket DataDate
2508    0-29    2018-03-01
2347    0-29    2018-03-02
2283    0-29    2018-03-03
1950    0-29    2018-03-05
1858    0-29    2018-03-06
1773    0-29    2018-03-07
1706    0-29    2018-03-08
1583    0-29    2018-03-09
1452    0-29    2018-03-10
1237    0-29    2018-03-12
1077    0-29    2018-03-13
920 0-29    2018-03-14
725 0-29    2018-03-15
628 0-29    2018-03-16
611 0-29    2018-03-17
555 0-29    2018-03-19
532 0-29    2018-03-20
510 0-29    2018-03-21
484 0-29    2018-03-22
462 0-29    2018-03-23
463 0-29    2018-03-24
441 0-29    2018-03-26
434 0-29    2018-03-27
429 0-29    2018-03-28
409 0-29    2018-03-29
326 0-29    2018-03-30
313 0-29    2018-03-31
2414    0-29    2018-04-02
2262    0-29    2018-04-03
2067    0-29    2018-04-04`

[Desired SSRS Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgqtK.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post a sample of your dataset output to get a meaningful answer. Please update your post with sample data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield my apologies as I rarely use this site and want to make sure I follow the proper formatting. How should I post the dataset output to ensure proper format?

Comment: No problem. I usually paste it in then format as a code block. As long as people can copy/paste it (and read it!) then it will be fine. Post a sample as small as you can but that still enough to work with.